# pushed off by the recycler view button and notifyItemRemoved

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

So my problem is: when I add many items to the Recycler View, the button below which has to add more items, dissapear because he is pusshed off from the screen by the recycler. [before add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDTSb.png) and [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JQAr.png). There is no button :/

here is the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".AddActivityFormEvent">


    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="date"
    android:ems="14"
    android:id="@+id/dateField"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:hint="@string/data"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_today"
    android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog"

    />

    <Button

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="time"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:hint="@string/czas"
    android:id="@+id/timeField"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/dateField"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dateField"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/dateField"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_time"
    android:onClick="showTimePickerDialog"/>

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dateField">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        >


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/activityRecyclerView"
            android:elevation="15dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/addActivityEvent"
        android:text="Dodaj aktywność"

        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/testButton"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

By the way, how to get actual position of the view holder? I ask because when I delete item first time, it return correct index, but each next time it is one more, for example when I delete first item(index 0) it returns 1
here is an adapter with view holder:

```
public class ActivityFormEventAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ActivityFormEventAdapter.ActivityFormEventViewHolder>{
ArrayList<ActivityFormEvent> adapter_list = new ArrayList<>();
AddActivityFormEvent addActivityFormEvent;

private static Button button;

Context ctx;
public ActivityFormEventAdapter(ArrayList<ActivityFormEvent> adapter_list,Context ctx){
    this.adapter_list=adapter_list;
    this.ctx=ctx;
    addActivityFormEvent= (AddActivityFormEvent) ctx;
    button= (Button) addActivityFormEvent.findViewById(R.id.testButton);
}

public ActivityFormEventViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_form_event_card,parent,false);
    ActivityFormEventViewHolder activityFormEventViewHolder = new ActivityFormEventViewHolder(view,addActivityFormEvent);
    return activityFormEventViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ActivityFormEventViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.activityName.setText(adapter_list.get(position).getActivityForm().getName());
    holder.duration.setText(adapter_list.get(position).getTime());
    holder.burnedKcalPerHour.setText(adapter_list.get(position).getActivityForm().getBurnedKcalPerHour());
    holder.burnedKcal.setText(adapter_list.get(position).getBuriedKcal());

    holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            adapter_list.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return adapter_list.size();
}

public static class ActivityFormEventViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    AddActivityFormEvent addActivityFormEvent;
    EditText activityName;
    EditText duration;
    EditText burnedKcalPerHour;
    EditText burnedKcal;
    ImageButton deleteButton;

    public ActivityFormEventViewHolder(View itemView,AddActivityFormEvent addActivityFormEvent) {
        super(itemView);
        activityName = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.activityName);
        duration = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.duration);
        burnedKcalPerHour = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.burnedKcalPerHour);
        burnedKcal = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.kcalExercise);
        deleteButton = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
        this.addActivityFormEvent = addActivityFormEvent;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What happens if you add `android:layout_above="@+id/addActivityEvent"` to the linear layout and set the buttons to be aligned to the bottom rather than under the linear layout?

Comment: result:
[3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/nDjrA.png
i want that button to scroll together with the recycler, i mean it disappears when recycler is on the top(if there are enough elements) but shows with the reaching bottom.

Comment: Ok, i coped with that just added button to the card... it has status gone when it isn't last one... works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay try this, here bottom view must have minimum height = height of Buttom that attached and it's height must be programmatically set to height of all view - recyclerview content height. Try to change height of bottom view to see the difference in preview.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dateField">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_space_holder"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/activityRecyclerView"
                android:elevation="15dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        </LinearLayout>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/addActivityEvent"
            android:text="Dodaj aktywność"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:id="@+id/bottom_space_holder"
            android:text="Dodaj aktywność"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: testButton, as the name says, is just for tests so it will be deleted.
Anyway, it didn't help even when i exchanged that fraze

Comment: I updated answer update bottom <View height programmatically and you will get what you want (must have minimum height of height that your button has )

Comment: It's ok but the button is always at the bottom of the screen so...
maybe it can be programically earned that animation of changing layout size will be fluent (as same as button possition) but it is not worth of time :/

Comment: it's not, now it deppends on view size that is attached at bottom if you will change it height for example to 100 you wil lsee in android studio in preview that your button actually attached to recycler view

Comment: Ok, i know it but my RecyclerView hasnt fixed size, it has hold 1 element(at the beggining) as same as 100. When i do so as you said animation will crack sometimes (i tried it, when i delete card animation happens and then button teleports immiedietly). Or maybe i am doing something wrong.

Comment: to do proper animation best is to extend from Animation class and change layout params in interaction and reassign them - then animation will be smooth )

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you place the `Button` below the `RecyclerView` using `layout_below` and the `RecyclerView`'s height is set to `wrap_content`. This means that once the `RecyclerView`'s content exceeds the screens height, the `Button` will fall off the screen, because it is placed below the `RecyclerView`.

To fix this issue, you should align your `Button` to the parent's bottom (using `layout_alignParentBottom`) and layout your `RecyclerView` above the button (using `layout_above` and `layout_alignParentTop`), this way the `Button` will always be placed and visible at the bottom of your screen.

Comment: Exacly,  but i want that the button is visible only when i see the end of the list :) and it scrolls together

Comment: Alright, then you should either:
Place your RecyclerView with setFixedHeight to true in a ScrollView and place the Button below the Recyclerview. (easy solution but does not have the best performance, since the RecyclerView's items wont be recycled when fixed height is set to true)

Or you could add an extra row with the Button to your RecyclerView's Adapter using different ViewTypes, and use a callbacklistener to your Activity/Fragment to add a new item to your ArrayList and notify the dataset is changed. (which obviously is more complicated than the first option)

Comment: About first option, button is dissapearing, fixed size makes it floating when i delete all items for example and call notifyItemRemoved... so no, wrong answer.. :/